# Can anyone recommend a mouse tracking/recording service for usability studies?

Tags: usability

I am after a service like userfly, that is not userfly. Userfly is renders the site badly and means the information is unreliable.

Comment: I wonder what the state of this is now (2013).

Comment: I wonder what the state of this is now (2015).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Crazy Egg](http://www.crazyegg.com/), or even, [UserTesting.com](http://www.usertesting.com/).

Used and recommend the former, been meaning to use the latter.